# Sorting a set of 2D parallel line segments that are defined by their end points

Tags: linear-algebra

Suppose I have a set of 2D parallel line segments on an XY plane defined by their end points, and the set is out of order, and I need to sort them such that they are ordered correctly in either direction of their shared normal vector.

What might be the best way to do this?

Edit:
A picture may be helpful in explaining my intentions. The output of the solution should be either of two mappings shown in the image, which it is, is not important. The line segments are not guaranteed to all share a perpendicular line passing through all of them, hence why I would like to solve using a normal vector.

I can't post the image directly as I do not have enough reputation, so here is the link: https://i.stack.imgur.com/uzUsm.jpg

Comment: What do you mean by defined by their endpoints? Lines in $\mathbb{R}^n$ are generally defined by a point on that line and a direction vector. If they are lines they really shouldn't have "endpoints".

Comment: Edited to add clarity. They are in fact line segments.

Comment: Okay. Now you are going to have to clarify by what you mean by ordering them. As your question is stated it seems as though you are trying to order them based on their endpoints, however arbitrary points in $\mathbb{R}^n$ with $n\geq 2$ don't have an obvious ordering like numbers in $\mathbb{R}$ do.

Comment: Perhaps I was unclear. The line segments are all parallel and so they all share the same normal vector on a 2D plane. I want to order them according to their shared normal vector, meaning there are two possible orderings (and I don't care which I end up with, only that they are ordered according to where they intersect the normal vector). Is that more clear?

Comment: See picture attached to original question for an example. And thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the endpoints of a line segment are $\mathbf p$ and $\mathbf q$, then the distance of the line through these points from the origin is the length of their projection onto the normal $\mathbf n$ to the line. For a fixed unit normal this is simply the absolute value of the dot product of $\mathbf p$ or $\mathbf q$ with $\mathbf n$. Retain the sign so that you have a signed distance that also tells you which side of the origin you’re on relative to the direction of the normal and use this scalar projection as the sort key.

You can easily find this common unit normal either by taking the cross product of the homogeneous coordinates of a pair of endpoints and then normalizing the first two components, or by rotating the difference $\mathbf q-\mathbf p$ 90°, which is just a matter of a swap of coordinates and a sign change. As long as you use the same normal for all of the dot products, you don’t even have to normalize it.

Comment: Thank you. I was able to write the correct code using this answer. I would note that since I am working in 2D the first option in the second paragraph was not possible, since cross products have a different meaning in 2D. The rotated difference works well in 2D, however. 

I am becoming curious how the solution can be generalized now (for parallel arcs in 3D space especially), but I will return to ask regarding more complex extensions of this kind of sorting when the time comes.

Comment: @KieranCoulter Note that I wrote “using homogeneous coordinates” when I suggested a cross product. The components of the resulting triple are exactly the coefficients in an implicit Cartesian equation $ax+by+c=0$ of the line through the two points. The rotated difference is much cheaper to compute, though it shouldn’t matter much since you’re only doing it once per sort.

Comment: @KieranCoulter As for the generalization to arcs and other curve segments, you’ll need to have a solid definition of the sort order, which could be tricky to formulate.